# swing BoxLayout not working

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have read many subjects here but I can't make my window with the layout I want.
I simply want all my graphic object to be in a row style like in the first picture here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html

I've tried GridLayout but it still make my first button giant and then, as I add textfields, it's getting smaller and smaller?!

Here is my code without all the imports:

```
public class TestScrollPane extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
Dimension dim = new Dimension(200 , 50);
JButton button;
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(panel);

public TestScrollPane(){
    scrollpane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    this.add(scrollpane);

    //panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    this.setSize(300, 400);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    button = new JButton("click me");
    button.setPreferredSize(dim);
    panel.add(button);
    button.addActionListener(this);
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource() == button ){

        JTextField txt = new JTextField(); // we add a new button
        txt.setPreferredSize(dim);
        panel.add(txt);

        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this); // refresh jframe
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    TestScrollPane test = new TestScrollPane();
}
}
```

I just want to have one button per row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `BoxLayout` will respect the minimum/maximum sizes of a component.

For some reason the maximum height of a text field is unlimited so the text field gets all the space available.

So you can do something like:

```
JTextField txt = new JTextField(10); // we add a new button
//txt.setPreferredSize(dim); // don't hardcode a preferrd size of a component.
txt.setMaximumSize(txt.getPreferredSize());
```

Also:

```
//SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this); // refresh jframe
```

Don't use the above method. That is used for a LAF change.

Instead when you add/remove components from a visible GUI you should use:

```
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

Comment: thanks dude, i knew that it was something about preferredsize but I thought that  button.setPreferredSize(dim); was sufficient.

Comment: @zogota `but I thought that button.setPreferredSize(dim); was sufficient.` - you should get rid of that statement. You should not be trying to control the preferred size of any component.

Comment: thank you for the tip! I tried _button.setMinimumSize(dim)_ and I did the same for the textfield but as I add textfields, the button decreases its size and so do they until a certain size that is inferior to the _dim_ Dimension. What is happening ?

Comment: @zogota, when you create a JTextField you should use: `JTextField textField = new JTextField(10)`. The number will suggest a preferred size for the text field so that it displays a minimum of 10 characters.

Comment: it works great with the column parameter but does it mean that I can't hardcore the height of my textfield ?

Comment: I already told you that you should not be attempting to control the size (width or height) of a component. The text field will automatically determine is size based on the Font (which may be different on different platforms).